# Calculate scale and precision for two number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following operation :

```
SELECT 9 / 2;
```

The result is 4 instead of 4.5. I modified my code to :

```
DECLARE @p1 AS INT = 9, @p2 AS INT = 2;
SELECT CAST(@p1 AS NUMERIC(12, 2)) / CAST(@p2 AS NUMERIC(12, 2));
```

The new result is  :

> 4.500000000000000

Why I have extra 0 in my result ?

Answer (score 2):

This answer does NOT answer the OP's explicit question of "Why I have extra 0 in my result ?".  Sandra's good post does that.

However, this answer DOES show a way to do such calculations without having to put up with all the trailing zeros, if that's what you need to do.

While you really DO need to read the article at the link that Sandra provided in her good post (**especially since multiple consecutive mathematical operations can reduce both precision and scale to the detriment of accuracy**), there's a really slick trick that I learned from Peter "Peso" Larsson that does the necessary calculation and produces a non-trailing zero result.  Here are the different methods that people try and the one that "Peso" demonstrated.  It works because of the way that SQL Server handles "Engineering Notation", which can be accomplished by adding an abbreviated "Engineering Notation" for the value of "0" in the form of "0E" (which is the same as "0E0" or any legal value of "n" for "0En") to the Numerator (in this case).

```
 SELECT  IntegerMath = v.Numerator/v.Denominator
        ,ZeroTrick   = (0.0+v.Numerator)/v.Denominator
        ,Conversion  = CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,2),v.Numerator)/v.Denominator
        ,PesoTrick   = (0E + v.Numerator)/v.Denominator
   FROM (--===== Contains Numerators and Denominators left to right
         VALUES
         (9,2)
        ,(2,9)
        ,(1,3)
        ,(3,1)
        ,(10,4)
        ,(4,10)
        ,(1000,5)
        ,(5,1000)
        ) v (Numerator,Denominator)
;
```

Here's are the results from the code above...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The rules for determining the precision and scale of the result of the computation can be
found at [Precision, scale, and Length (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx).

The operation here is division. The applicable formula to calculate
the precision here is p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1), which when applied to our inputs
results in 27.
The formula for the scale is max(6, s1 + p2 + 1), which in this case results in 15.